# Django: Default value in Database, not just ORM

Tags: django, database, orm, default-value

I would like to have a default value for a column in the **database**, not just the django orm.

Related ticket is in state "wontfix": https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470

What is the preferred way to create a default value in the relational database?

In my case it is a BooleanField which should default to FALSE.

I use PostgreSQL, but AFAIK this should not matter in this context.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it like this. The file was created with `manage.py makemigrations`. I added only the line at the bottom.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='State',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=256, serialize=False, primary_key=True)),
                ('state', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ],
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),

        ### The following line was added 
        migrations.RunSQL('alter table box_state alter column state set default false')
    ]
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do like this:

```
class MYModel(models.Model):
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK the default is handled in the ORM only. The database schema does not have it. I provided a link to the relevant ticket.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is incorrect, Django does not set the default in the DB, as the original question says.

Comment: then you should go with fixtures

Comment: @aryan fixtures don't solve my problem. I have other applications which don't use the django ORM which make SQL-INSERTs. These INSERTs should have defaults. These defaults need to come from the database.